# WebTileLayer not loading in ESRI map

Tags: geojson, mapbox, vector-tiles, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to add a WebTileLayer to my ESRI map and the code runs without any problems. I can see the protobuf files being received by looking at the network inspector, however they do not appear on the map.

```
<script>
require([
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/MapView",
  "esri/layers/WebTileLayer",
  "esri/layers/support/TileInfo",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Map, MapView, WebTileLayer, TileInfo) {
  var map = new Map({
    basemap: "streets"
  });

  var view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    zoom: 18,
    center: [-89.37318187952042, 45.61155180826724]
  });
  var vtlayer = new WebTileLayer("http://localhost:3000/featurelayers/{level}/{col}/{row}.pbf");

  map.add(vtlayer);
  vtlayer.visible = true;
});
</script>
```

I have tried styling the layer hoping that they might just be hidden but that didnt seem to help. I am using ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the Leaflet ESRI plug-in for Javascript. See the following link and the other examples in the GitHub repo for different options on loading your basemap: https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/. Hope it helps.